# Dealing with geom_text size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm building a heatmap using ggplot2 geom_tile and adding some text to each cell as follows:

[image]

The code I'm using is below.  But as the number of tiles in the heatmap change I need to adjust the text size.  Is there someway to get the tile size and use that to set the text size?  Or autoscale the text?  Or even build an image of the text and scale that as an overlay on the tile?

```
  text.size.corr  =  0.9
  text.vjust.corr = -0.6
  text.size.misc  =  0.4
  text.vjust.misc =  0.8
  text.lineheight.misc = 0.8
  
  ggheatmap =
    ggplot(res2.flat, 
           aes(column, row, fill=cor)
           )+  
      geom_tile(color = "white") +
      geom_text( aes( column, row, label=cor ),   # add Corr  value
                 color = "black", 
                 size = text.size.corr,
                 vjust= text.vjust.corr
                 ) +
      geom_text( aes( column, row, label=glue("{row}:{column}\np={formatPvalue(p)}\nn={n}") ), # p value
             color = "black", 
             size = text.size.misc,
             vjust= text.vjust.misc,
             lineheight = text.lineheight.misc
             ) +
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `ggfittext`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggfittext)

data <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~value, ~p, ~n,
  1, 1, 0.78, 0.05, 132,
  1, 2, 0.67, 0.04, 421,
  2, 1, 0.72, 0.01, 400,
  2, 2, 0.23, 0.01, 300
)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  geom_fit_text(aes(label = paste0(p, "\n", n)), size = 1e3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks for this. It looks like it calculates a different size for each call though, which in my opinion makes the resulting output look a bit amateurish.  But I'm going to dig through the code and see if I can figure out exactly how it does its magic and maybe derive a solution from that.

Comment: @Ian I am running in to the exact same issue (ggfittext mostly does what I want, but I want one maximum size across all cells, not maximum size per cell), did you figure out a way to solve this?

Comment: @NicholasRoot  I regret that I didn't, sorry.